# PhpQuery installation

Tags: php

I'm trying  to install [PhpQuery]

I used 'composer require phpquery/phpquery' to install it my web root it creates a folder vendor, ran 'composer install' but nothing was installed. Then I followed the instructions:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpQuery\PhpQuery ;
```

I get a warning that autoload.php cant be found, so I changed the line to

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

and it finds the autoload.php, but I then get the error that it can't find the class "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PhpQuery\PhpQuery' not found " the phpquery.php is in the /vendor/phpquery/phpquery folder, so i tried

```
use \vendor\phpquery\phpquery
```

but to no avail. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Check the namespace of the phpquery class file

Comment: You so not use path in `use`: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/phpquery/phpquery

Comment: Try running `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: Do you mean the phpquery.php file? If so the code is:namespace PhpQuery;

class PhpQuery{
 private $doc,$xpath;
 function __construct(){

 }

Comment: composer dumpautoload does not change things

Comment: Check is in `vendor/composer/installed.json` you have phpQuery with correct paths. (and count `vendor`directories)

Comment: Ok I looked at vendor/composer/installed.json and the code is  "name": "phpquery/phpquery",  and         "installation-source": "dist",
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "PhpQuery\\": "src/"
            }
        },